# spring mvc @requestmapping best practice

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, spring-mvc

Checked the official ref, found a million ways to do things.
I guess I have 2 set of use cases. 
1. return customized http response, basically I am responsible for filling in status code, response body(either XML or JSON or text). 
2. return Model and View. view is a jsp page typically and fill in the view with data from modle.

My question is which is a better way to go? it possible to mix them together.  In my first use set, is it possible to return a View? also is it possible to have both on them in one method. something like if A return customized http response, if B return ModelAndView.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value from any request handling method (*i.e.* on marked with the `@RequestMapping` annotation must either identify a view (that will generate the HTTP Response) or generate the HTTP Response itself.

Each handler method stands alone; by that I mean, you can return a view name from some handler methods and generate the HTTP Response in other handler methods.

Check out **15.3.2.3 Supported handler method arguments and return types** in the Spring 3x reference document at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/

As an option to generating the HTTP Response in the handler method, you could setup multiple view resolvers; one or more for normal view resolution (jsp pages, tiles, *etc.*) and one or more for "special" view resolution (XML, JSON, *etc.*).  For the "special" views, you may want to create your own view class that extends `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView`.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish something similar to what you are describing using the `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`, which can deal with serving different content based on a request, with no changes required to your `@RequestMapping` annotations, or in fact anything in you're controllers.

There are plenty of resources on how to use this method, including [this](http://blog.anthonychaves.net/2010/02/01/spring-3-0-web-mvc-and-json/) and [this](http://www.rickherrick.com/?q=node/63)